# Access all nodes in xml using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xml-parsing

I have xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<UpdateMemberHireStatus xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <member>
    <HireAvailability>
      <code>1</code>
      <name>פנוי</name>
    </HireAvailability>
    <HireRejectReason>
      <code>2</code>
      <name>wow</name>
    </HireRejectReason>
    <IdNumber>43504349</IdNumber>
    <note> </note>
  </member>
</UpdateMemberHireStatus>
```

and I want to use LINQ to access all the nodes in the xml.

Here's what I have tried:

```
XNamespace ns = "tempuri.org/";
IEnumerable<HireStatus> status = from r in doc.Descendants(ns + "UpdateMemberHireStatus")
                                              .Descendants(ns + "member") 
                                 select new HireStatus() { }; 
return status.ToList();
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: This might be useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738877/traverse-every-element-in-xml-tree-using-linq-to-xml

Comment: I have a class that represents the xml and i want to use linq in order to insert values.to be forthcoming i don't really know where and how to start. i have used linq before but in easier cases.                     public HireStatus()
        {
            HireAvail = new HireAvailability();
            HireRejectReason = new HireRejectReason();
        }
        public HireAvailability HireAvail { get; set; }
        public HireRejectReason HireRejectReason { get; set; }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }

Comment: Possible duplicate of --> traverse every element in xml tree using linq to xml --> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738877/traverse-every-element-in-xml-tree-using-linq-to-xml)

Comment: Tried it it wasn't exactly what i need, i need to insert values in the proprieties of the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx)

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(XMLStream);
var allEle = xml.Descendants("UpdateMemberHireStatus"); //you can do linq now.
```

Comment: XNamespace ns = "http://tempuri.org/";
                IEnumerable<HireStatus> status = from r in doc.Descendants(ns + "UpdateMemberHireStatus").Descendants(ns + "member")
                                                 select new HireStatus()
                                                   {
                                                      
                                                   };
                return status.ToList();                                      This is what i done so far

Comment: @Danny so what the issue then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XDocument also in the following way:

```
        string xmlPath = "D://member.xml";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlPath);
        doc.LoadXml(xdoc.ToString());
        var memberStatus= (from mem in xdoc.Descendants("member")
                               select mem);

        foreach (XElement element in memberStatuses.ToList())            
            IEnumerable<XNode> nodes = element.Nodes();
```

Answer (score -1):

var x  = XElement.Load(XMLStream);

var all = x.DescendantNodes();